# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS no longer boots after CTRL+ALT+DEL on the decryption screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, encryption

So whenever I boot my computer, and I'm presented with a decryption screen shortly after the Grub menu (ENTER Passphrase:) and press CTRL+ALT+DEL or physically press the restart button to reset the system without unlocking the disk for whatever reason, the system will no longer start. It'll be just a blank screen.

What I have to do then is go into recovery mode, reset Grub, and then boot normally, this seems to fix it but I'm not sure if it's a Grub issue or whether regenerating the initrd etc.. is what fixes it.

This happens 100% of the time when I do this. It's not a major issue but I'd like to know if anyone knows how I could prevent this.